# Android Studio duplicates randomly import lines after hot reload

Tags: macos, flutter, dart, android-studio-3.0, code-duplication

Is this an official bug or am I doing something wrong?

I'm using Android 3.5.3 and every time I run my Flutter project, some of my import lines are randomly being duplicated or even at times even triplicated.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have the same problem. Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You can set Android Studio to auto import files.

So my bet is to disable this function or set it to `Ask` in

`File -> Settings -> Editor -> Auto Import -> Java` and `Dart`